# Can't submit form after event preventDefault

Tags: javascript

I have a form to validate using both PHP and javascript.
PHP side works great. Javascript validates correctly but when submit button is clicked the form won't submit.

I have set onsubmit="return validate(event);" inside form element.

Inside validate(event), in the first line i have event.preventDefault(). I have checked that form validates correctly, and form is prevented from submitting.

In the end of validate(event), I have in the effect of, if no error, submit the form.

I have tried

```
document.getElementById("checkout").submit();

$('form').submit();

$('#checkout').unbind('submit').submit();

$('form')[0].submit();

$('#checkout').off('submit');
```

Here's summary of relevant code bits.

```
<form method="post" action="thanks-order.php" id="checkout" name="checkout" onsubmit="return validate(event);">
...
<input type="hidden" name="flag">
<p><input type="submit" name="pay" value="Pay"></p>
...
</form>
<script>
function validate(event)
{
   //prevent form submission
   event.preventDefault();
   //reset error flag
   document.getElementsByName("flag")[0].value = "";

   //
   //form validation code
   //
   ...
   //if error flag is not set to "error"
   if(getFlag()=="")
   {
      //submit form
      //all of these doesn't work
      // document.getElementById("checkout").submit();
      // $('checkout').submit();
      // $('#checkout').unbind('submit').submit();
      // $('form')[0].submit();
      // $('#checkout').off('submit'); // then submit

   }
}
...
</script>
```

When submit button is clicked and there are errors, error messages are displayed correctly. However, when there are no errors, form submission has no effect on inserting record into database (by way of thanks-order.php).

Comment: that's because you always `preventDefault` on submit, so calling submit won't submit

Comment: put preventDefault in an else block after `if(getFlag()=="")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are running preventDefault unconditionally in validate, it always prevents the form from submitting matter how the submit is triggered

Simply run the preventDefault constionally, like the following:

```
function validate(event) {
   //reset error flag
   document.getElementsByName("flag")[0].value = "";

   //
   //form validation code
   //
   ...
   //if error flag is not set to "error"
   if(getFlag()=="") {
      //submit form
      //all of these doesn't work
      // document.getElementById("checkout").submit();
      // $('checkout').submit();
      // $('#checkout').unbind('submit').submit();
      // $('form')[0].submit();
      // $('#checkout').off('submit'); // then submit

   } else {
       //prevent form submission
       event.preventDefault();
   } 
}
```